# Frequency content of a noisy signal

Tags: fourier-transform, noise, autocorrelation

To find the frequency content of a noisy signal (PSD), there are two methods below:

#1 Take the fourier transform of its power signal (square the noisy signal)

#2 Find the autocorrelation function of the signal, then take the fourier transform

It seems that they achieve the same result. If so, what is the difference between doing #1 and #2?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes!

> #1 Take the fourier transform of its power signal **(square the noisy signal)**

That's for anything but a constant zero signal **not** the same as the PSD estimate you get from your #2.

You might mean that you take the Fourier transform's magnitude square, not that you transform the square of the signal. *Important* difference. But even then, the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation of a stochastic process is the definition of the power spectral density (PSD). And what you describe in #1 seems to be an estimate of the PSD based on a finite observation of a single realization of the stochastic process – which isn't identical to the PSD. It is only equivalent in *expectation*, i.e. averaged over all possible realizations of noise+signal, and even then only under the assumption that the properties of that noisy signals are ergodicity, weak sense stationarity and bounded variance. See the *Wiener-Khinchin theorem*'s requirements!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let's say if I have a sample of a certain noisy signal (WSS and ergodic had I gotten an infinite samples of it) and compute the autocorrelation on it using the finite length data and obtain PSD from taking the fourier transform of it. Would the PSD be more accurate as compared to simply taking the fourier transform on the magnitude^2 of the signal? What's the intuitive difference between the two procedures?

Comment: The PSD itself is necessarily more accurate at describing the PSD than any PSD estimate could be, yes. You do need to know the autocorrelation function of your process to transform it, which you usually don't! If you estimate that from a finite observation, then it fully depends on the properties of your process and how you estimate the autocorrelation function, as well as how you measure "accurate" whether a { observation -> estimate autocorr -> Fourier transform } algorithm is more "accurate" than a { observation -> Fourier transform -> take magnitude squared } algorithm. No general answer.

Comment: you don't obtain a PSD, you obtain a *PSD estimate*. And the rest still stands: which one is more "accurate" depends on your mathematical definiton of "accurate", your method of estimating the autocorrelation function that you transform, and the properties of your signal and your noise. No general answer is possible.

Comment: So which method is closer to the result obtained from a spectral analyzer? In general, I am not able to intuitively connect the math behind the two methods. They just feel so different, method #2 having to determine the autocorrelation first; yet, they both yield PSD "estimate". Thanks again.

Comment: Am I able to think like this? They are similar because { observation -> estimate autocorr -> Fourier transform } and { observation -> Fourier transform -> take magnitude squared } are essentially the same procedure. The autocorr is like convolution in time domain; hence the same as "squared mag in freq domain"?

Comment: I'll have to think about this for a moment, I'm afraid, I'll not be able to do that today. You're making an assumption on how you estimate the autocorrelation function, that I think needs writing down – there's more than one method.